# Can you safely connect NextJS to MongoDB without anything in between?

Tags: mongodb, security, next.js

Is it safe to connect NextJS running on a Digital Ocean droplet (virtual server) directly to MongoDB running on a Digital Ocean virtual server?  I hear different things.  Some people say that you shouldn't use any "full stack" frameworks like NextJS or Angular without a backend in between because if you are using Chrome Inspection tools, you can see everything needed to hack your database. This is what an instructor on Udemy says (starting at 1 min 48 sec) -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsAalk1NpVk

But then I hear other people saying "it's safe" and then they talk about hosting on Vercel (which has different functionality and could be prohibitively expensive for me if there was a denial of service attack or we just get more successful than I can afford.)  And  they hook it to serverless. (also pricey) and Mongo Atlas (pricey and has other features).  Someone else said "eahhhh.. It used to be a problem but not with modern NextJS"

Soooo... what should I believe?

This is for a non-profit website around politician and election information, so we are at a weird crossroad where security is really important, we could have a lot of users, but we have no money to pay for anything. Virtual servers have the advantages of being inexpensive and predictably priced.  If we get too many people using the site, it becomes slow as hell or crashes, but I don't get a bill that forces us to go bancrupt.   I am just learning everything and the fewer languages I have to learn, the better.  Soooo.. I am very open to ideas here.  Thanks.

I tried numerous google searches but because my knowlege of NextJS isn't great, I didn't understand whose word to trust.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the instructor. he is basically saying not to write sensitive data on the client side because it will be added to the client bundle and be visible through the Chrome tools.

Comment: Since NextJS has all the code intermingled on the same physical server, what is the best practice to make sure I don't expose my authorizations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is almost safe it depends on your app/website security of course, but referring to your question,
the instructor on Udemy here explains that you should never try to use queries or database credentials from the frontend code like angular or react...
instead, it would be best if you did that in the backend,
this is because, on the front end, the user can inspect the code, but if it is used in the backend the users cannot see the queries or credentials.
Here you can see why it's the best choice to use MongoDB with NodeJs:
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-MongoDB-with-Node-js

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the educational link.  So if it's not safe to go straight from NextJS to Mongo, then why did they bother integrating NodeJS into NextJS?  Were they thinking that people wouldn't care about security or were they thinking about some future appication?

Comment: @spencersnygg It is safe to use MongoDB with Next.js as long as the code lives on the server-side (API routes or React Server Components).

Comment: @juliomalves  So you mean, like so long as the particlar page/component is server side rendered vs client side rendered in the settings or is there a particular folder in NextJS that i should keep my calls?

Comment: @spencersnygg It depends where the calls are made in your components. If using the `app` folder you'll want them in RSC; if using the `pages` folder you'll want them in `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`.